# how to create seo friendly url as per wordpress in core php without using .htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

SEO friendly URL without ht-access in core PHP as per WordPress.
only use with database .

how to create seo friendly url as per wordpress in core php without using .htaccess?

wordpress work on this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sevenoutsource/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/index.php [L]
```

Like this htaccess create on core php
and not want to add any rule like

```
RewriteRule ^userprofile.html$ /user_profile.php [L]
```

this url want to store in database and rewrite from that.

Comment: i have no idea for that how to do this

Comment: Do u understand my question or not?what i want to do actually?

Comment: You do realise that wordpress also need `.htaccess` for pretty URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You mean making not change to .htaccess and change url type it has one possibly way but it's also have some limit like this if your custom url type http://sitename.com/%postname% just only to making change that %postname% part

http://sangkrit.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sangkrit.net_setting-url-hierarchy-wordpress-post2_thumb.png

on database that table is wp_posts

also check this
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes